# Connecting remotly to a mysql server over ssh using c# for windowsce

Tags: c#, ssh

I tryed to connect  remotly to a MySql server over SSH protocole from a  windowsce 5.0 client using c#.

I installed the connector/net and I tryed to use the Tamir.SharpSsh library but I got this message

> Impossible de charger le type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session' à partir
>   de l'assembly 'Tamir.SharpSSH, Version=1.1.1.13, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for people having  the same situation there   is the solution without ssh connection

1/ add the MySql.SqlData.MyClient librery compact framework
2/add the privilege to access remotly to your MySql server